# How do i get the wsdl when using soap over tcp?

Tags: soap, tcp, wsdl

As noted, i have the host and server... but how does one make a wsdl request over tcp?

That is, i want to see the returned wsdl file!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the format to get the wsdl file from the server

```
http://url:port/WebServicesName?wsdl
```